# Combinatorial Analysis question

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

So, i want to know how many combinations/permutations/variations are possible in the following case:
Let's suppose we have to calculate the number of all possible words of length N that can be formed with the letters "A" , "B", and "C" assuming that every word contains all three letters. For example, all words of size 4 that contains A, B and C are :

> AABC AACB ABAC ABBC ABCA ABCB ABCC ACAB ACBA ACBB ACBC ACCB BAAC BABC
>   BACA BACB BACC BBAC BBCA BCAA BCAB BCAC BCBA BCCA CAAB CABA CABB CABC
>   CACB CBAA CBAB CBAC CBBA CBCA CCAB CCBA

and we have 36 possibilities.
I want to know how to calculate the number of possibilities given any number of letters/symbols for any length.

This is an example of P ( size of the word ), and S ( number of letters/symbols) :

```
P: 3 S: 2 6
P: 4 S: 2 14
P: 4 S: 3 36
P: 5 S: 2 30
P: 5 S: 3 150
P: 5 S: 4 240
P: 6 S: 2 62
P: 6 S: 3 540
P: 6 S: 4 1560
P: 6 S: 5 1800
P: 7 S: 2 126
P: 7 S: 3 1806
P: 7 S: 4 8400
P: 7 S: 5 16800
P: 7 S: 6 15120
P: 8 S: 2 254
P: 8 S: 3 5796
P: 8 S: 4 40824
P: 8 S: 5 126000
P: 8 S: 6 191520
P: 8 S: 7 141120
P: 9 S: 2 510
P: 9 S: 3 18150
P: 9 S: 4 186480
P: 9 S: 5 834120
```

I also made this question on reddit and a guy gave some useful observations, but i still don't know exactly a generalized way to calculate this. So i accept any help, thanks! =]

[Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/askmath/comments/6xp5l9/combinatorial_analisys_question/)

Answer (score 2):

You basically want to calculate the number $F(P,S)$ of all surjective functions from $P$ to $S$:

$F(P,S) = \sum_{i=0}^{S-1} (-1)^i (S-i)^P \binom{S}{i} $.

Taking one of your examples with $P=4$, $S=2$:

$F(4,2) = (-1)^0 (2)^4 \binom{2}{0} + (-1)^1 (1)^4 \binom{2}{1} = 1*16*1 -1*1*2=14$

There is also a recurrence relations for this number:

$F(P,S) = S^P - \sum_{i=1}^{S-1}\binom{S}{S-i}F(P,S-i)$.

The formula comes from inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: See oeis A019538.